# ExtJS Datagrid last row textarea edit

Tags: javascript, extjs, datagrid, textarea

During development of regular Ext JS data grid with text area and cell editing support next issue found:
[image: issue screenshot]

On attempt to perform editing of last line of textarea field type, editing area appears to be sliced in the bottom by end of datagrid itself.

Is there any ways to avoid that behaviour?
Attempt to set style for datagrid wrapper on class **.x-grid-item-container** with height:100% solves that issue, but breaks scrolling of datagrid.

Example is here -- https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/af8, and that is reproducable on extjs 6 classic as well.

Comment: same bug problem getted for me, to solve i catched the code of ext 5 and modified the ext 6 one

Comment: maybe using also margin bottom you can make appear the textarea upper without losing the scrolling

Comment: Using textfield instead of textarea is not an option?

Comment: unfortunately, no. It should be multiline input.
@Mr.George thank for hint, checking code of extjs 5

Comment: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/classic/restful/restful.html have a look to this example, another idea to modify grids that can be used without bugs